# How to customize the styling of the radio buttons in an AlertDialog.Builder?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I'm wondering if there's a way to customize the look of the radio buttons in an AlertDialog.Builder?  I have a selector XML file that works great for my custom radio button images, but I don't know how to assign it to an AlertDialog.Builder.  Is it possible, or do I maybe need to create a completely custom Dialog?  Any help/advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set a custom layout to your alert dialog which will contain your custom radio buttons (maybe a static number or a listview of items containing radio buttons depending on what you need) but it is surely possible.

Me personally if your view has even a bit more functionality than the default and you can see its future getting more and more customized and extended, i always make a custom dialog extending the Dialog class. its about the same amount of work but can go a long way in improving and adding features.

Hope this helps.